# Firebase Id Token from Flutter App is not verified on the REST server

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter

I want support social login with firebase auth. But I want to keep user's detailed profiles in my own RDB .
I thought that after user signed in with social account I could get encoded token which contains user's id and email.
And then if I send the token to the REST server (I built it with spring boot), then the server can decode it to load user's detailed profile from RDB.

I followed the guide from this article.
https://blog.codemagic.io/firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-using-flutter/

I can see sign in process successfully done and the id token printed at the console.
the flutter(dart) code is below.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);

final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
name = user.displayName;
email = user.email;
imageUrl = user.photoUrl;
final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
await currentUser.getIdToken().then((value) => print(value.token));
```

I copied the token into the server modult to test it could be decoded with no problem.
I added firebase-admin dependency. and run it with java code below.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
.setDatabaseUrl("https://test-firebase-auth-token.firebaseio.com")
.build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

String firebaseToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ1OThkYjVjZ..."; // actually it's long string.

FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(firebaseToken);
System.out.println(decodedToken.getUid());
System.out.println(decodedToken.getEmail());
```

And I got an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Failed to verify the signature of Firebase ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.checkSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:154)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.verifyToken(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:92)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:426)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:423)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:388)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:362)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.main(DemoApplicationTests.java:36)
```

I tried it again with firebase-server-sdk dependency instead of firebase-admin.
And I got an another error message. (seems that it caused by same reason with above error message)

```
Caused by: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Token isn't signed by a valid public key
    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.verifyTokenAndSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:61)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.call(FirebaseAuth.java:146)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.call(FirebaseAuth.java:140)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks$1.run(Tasks.java:63)
```

I checked the token on this site.
https://jwt.io/

[image]

I wonder the token is really signed with a (private) key?
Then how jwt.io site decode it without knowing the key?

It seems like it is just encoded with open algorithm like base64. Isn't it?
If so... the token is not secure any more.

What's the problem with my application. or Do I have miss-conception on security?
Any comment will be welcomed. Thanks...

Comment: your code should be fine. please double check if the flutter project and the spring is in the same firebase project.

Comment: thanks for your comment LoL. I tested with different firebase project between client(flutter) and server(java). and got another error message. `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Token is not for this app` This message implies that flutter and java apps are configured to see the same firebase project in the first test.

Comment: I have the same problem in Flutter app but not in the web. The decoded kid seems missing from google's public key.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64519821/4693979), problem on print method. It has limited to ~1024 symbols.

You can print like this:

```
final idToken = await firebaseCredential.user!.getIdToken(true);
print(idToken.substring(0, 1000));
print(idToken.substring(1000));
```